# How to find DHCP server while configured with the static IP

Tags: windows-8, dhcp, windows-server-2012

I'm doing a lot of the weird remote management, due to the specific network configuration, I often need to switch a client from static to the dynamic address. In couple cases the third party DHCP server wasn't available.

My question is: how do I make sure that DHCP server exists on the network and responds properly before I switch the client to DHCP?

`netsh dhcp show server` doesn't seem to work.

Need it for Windows 7 and up without installing any third party apps.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't Windows still have the "fallback static" configuration panel?